# Convergent powers imply convergence in a complete noetherian local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a complete noetherian local ring, $d$ a positive integer, and $(f_n)_n$ a sequence of elements of $R$ that satisfies $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n^d = 0$ in $R$. Does this imply the convergence of $(f_n)_n$?

This appears in Prop. 2.3.5. of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.13040.pdf. There, the author shows that for arbitrary nonzero $f\in R$, $(\mathfrak{m}^a:f)$ defines the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology as $a$ varies, and then argues that $f_n^d\in\mathfrak{m}^a\Rightarrow f_n^{d-1}\in (\mathfrak{m}^a:f_n)$ implies the result by decreasing induction on $d$. I do not see the last induction part, hence the question. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have to say that there are more assumptions in the above arXiv paper. For example, $R$ is assumed to be integral normal. However, at first sight I omitted those that did not seem necessary. Indeed, the already given answer (that I do not still understand) does not seem like using them.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way different from the one suggested above, but I will abstain from claiming that my answer is the most helpful since the other answer suggest that this question was very trivial.

The following holds according to Lemme 2 in section 2 of https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-7/issue-none/La-notion-danneau-de-d%C3%A9composition/nmj/1118799555.pdf.

> Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be an noetherian integral local domain. Then, $R$ is dominated by a discrete valuation ring. That is, there is a DVR $S\subseteq\operatorname{Frac} R$ that includes $R$ and that has the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n}$ including $\mathfrak{m}$.

We can use this in our case. (I apologize for adding the new assumptions later.) The assumption on the convergence of $f_n^d$ implies that $f_n^d$ converges in $S$ with equipped with the $\mathfrak{n}$-adic topology. We can use the valuation of $S$ to show that $f_n$ converges in $S$. Since $\displaystyle\bigcap_{m = 1}^{\infty} (\mathfrak{n}^m\cap R)\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcap_{m = 1}^{\infty} \mathfrak{n}^m = 0$, by the lemma of Chevalley $\mathfrak{n}^m\cap R$ defines the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology, for which $f_n$ converges, too.

Comment: I noticed that about the reference, you can find a better statement at Hartshorne II, Exe. 4.11.

Comment: I also found that Commutative Ring Theory by Matsumura has a similar exercise 14.4.

Answer (score 0):

Now $f_n^d\in\mathfrak{m}^a\Rightarrow f_n^{d-1}\in (\mathfrak{m}^a:f_n)$.

Since the decreasing sequence $(\mathfrak{m}^{a}:f_n)$ defines the $m$-adic toplogy on $R$,   $\{f_n^{d-1}\}$ converges in $R$.

Now by the induction hypothesis, the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For different $m$ and $n$, $(\mathfrak{m}^a:f_m)$ and $(\mathfrak{m}^a:f_n)$ may "have different speed of convergence" while defining the same topology, and I was wondering if you could elaborate on why this does not matter.